# include_path changed but still same error

Tags: php, include-path

I try to use jpgraph but when I run the example0.php I get the error 500 .
The error log tells me that the php files called by examples.php are not in usr/shar/php.
I modified etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini has seen on a few sites :
    include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/var/www/html/"
after having done a reboot I still get the same error and the same error log as if the new include_path was not taken into account ( but is still modified in php.ini)

Comment: Error 500 tells me that you are accessing it through a web browser. The cli/php.ini file is settings for the command line interface, not the web server mod.

Comment: thank you for answer . Where is then the include_path which is used instead of the one in cli/php.ini ? The one that generate the error log .

Comment: Mine is /etc/php.ini, but that doesn't mean that yours is in the exact same location. You can avoid this issue by including the file with the full path, such as /path/to/where/you/have/some/file.php